# Validate phone number on React.js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to validate the phone field, to get all letters and dots with the code below.

```
validatePhone = () => {
        const sanitizedPhone = this.state.phone.replace(/\D/g, '');
        if (sanitizedPhone.length >= 10 && sanitizedPhone.length <= 11) {
            this.setState({ phone: sanitizedPhone });
            return true;
        }
        toast.error('Invalid phoneNumber.', {
            position: "top-center",
            autoClose: false,
            closeOnClick: true,
        });
        return false;
    }
```

When i trying `console.log(sanitizedPhone)` with dots in input like `11.97.4.4.51234` i get `11974451234` but after this, on `console.log(this.state.phone)` i get the older number `11.97.4.4.51234`

Comment: `setState` doesn't always update instantly. Console.log in you render method.

Comment: @its4zahoor i get the same error on submit form

Comment: You're using [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) so `this` inside it would have the same value just as before you assigned it.

Comment: When i use with callback @awran5, i got the same error

Comment: @LuizHenrique then please share complete relevant code or codesandbox. either you input field is not bind with state or your form data is not updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.

This is why you don't see your change right after you're using setState.

Comment: So what's the best way to handle this phone data and play at State?

Comment: what would you like to do with the sanitized phone number? 
can you provide more code of what you're trying to do?
you can use this https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-microservice-kqxcx

Comment: Since my country has some numbers with the 9 digit in front of the number, such as 11 95879-5791 or 11 8597-1346, I am trying to avoid having space, period or comma in the form.

Comment: @LuizHenrique I created this sample with functional component, is this the behavior you're looking for ?
https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-elion-39iri

Comment: I believe you did not save

Comment: @LuizHenrique try now